# Azure upload blob 403

Tags: angularjs, azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to upload file on one of my **Azure** `containers`

this is one of my request send with **ajax**:

```
headers: Object
Authorization: "SharedKey MYACCOUNT:ENC_KEY"
Content-Type: "application/octet-stream"
data: File
x-ms-blob-type: "BlockBlob"
x-ms-date: "Mon, 19 Oct 2015 13:54:53 GMT"
x-ms-version: "2009-09-19"
type: "PUT"
url: "https://MYACCOUNT.blob.core.windows.net/data-test"
```

for the **ENC_KEY** I use :

```
authorizationHeader =
  compute: (options, xhrOptions) ->
  sig = @_computeSignature(options, xhrOptions)
  result = 'SharedKey ' + options.storageAccount + ':' + sig
  result

_computeSignature: (options, xhrOptions) ->
          sigString = @_getSignatureString(options, xhrOptions)
          key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(options.primaryKey)
          hmac = CryptoJS.algo.HMAC.create(CryptoJS.algo.SHA256, key)
          hmac.update sigString
          hash = hmac.finalize()
          result = hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)
          result
```

any ideas?

**EDIT :**
all code for `authorizationHeader` -> 
https://gist.github.com/F4Ke/88debcede3b7e2312b11

2)

### ERROR RESPONSE :

```
PUT https://MYACCOUNT.blob.core.windows.net/data-test 403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.)
```

3)

```
#_getCanonicalizedHeadersString
itemcreation.coffee:232 x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob
x-ms-date:Mon, 19 Oct 2015 14:33:15 GMT
x-ms-version:2009-09-19

#_getSignatureString
PUT




application/octet-stream






x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob
x-ms-date:Mon, 19 Oct 2015 14:35:19 GMT
x-ms-version:2009-09-19
/MYACCOUNT/MYACCOUNT.blob.core.windows.net/data-test
```

Comment: Please add the code for `@_computeSignature` and the parameters you're passing to that function. Most likely you're missing one or the parameters there.

Comment: I'v post an gist in the edit

Comment: In the url parameter, is `data-test` the name of the container or the file you're trying to upload?

Comment: Please try by appending the name of the file you're trying to upload. So your url parameter should be `https://MYACCOUNT.blob.core.windows.net/data-test/file-name.ext`. I believe that should work.

Comment: Even with that -> same error message (in last edit)
probably and error with enc keys, but I have no idea

Comment: Can you please add the output of `_getSignatureString` and `_getCanonicalizedHeadersString` to your post.

Comment: `/MYACCOUNT/MYACCOUNT.blob.core.windows.net/data-test` is the problem. It should be `/MYACCOUNT/data-test/file-name`.

Comment: I guess, I'll try to fix that

Comment: Hum, no changes unfortunalty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92743/discussion-between-gaurav-mantri-and-f4ke).

Comment: If you figured it out could you post an answer? Otherwise I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The REST documentation describing how to sign a message can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx). You can also take a look at the node shared key implementation [hhere](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/fade01a1889e2b7899b17375fea985753c578a44/lib/common/signing/sharedkey.js) - might also help you...